# Получение полигона из geojson - не отображается цвет полигона на карте

Tags: leafletjs, geojson, gis

Связка wordpres + leaflet
В leaflet импортирую файл geojson сгенерированный на geojson.io - параметр fill задан и отображается.

```
    "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "stroke": "#555555",
        "stroke-width": 2,
        "stroke-opacity": 1,
        "fill-opacity": 0.5,
        "fill": "#ffff00"
      }
```

В сам leaflet файл подтягивается через

```
            var district_boundary = new L.geoJson();
            district_boundary.addTo(this.map);

            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/wp/poligon/map.geojson",
                success: function(data) {           
                    $(data.features).each(function(key, data) {
                        district_boundary.addData(data);
                    });
                }
            }).error(function() {});
```

Этот код оказался для меня единственным рабочим (не силен в js - поверхностно только).
Подскажите пожалуйста что не так делаю, или может быть направление в котором искать решение.
Спасибо.

Comment: в спецификации geojson нет цвета...

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то у вас в геоджейсоне заложен цвет заливки и координаты полигона. В случае, если на карте указаный полигон не отображается, попробуйте использовать вместо geojson kml или shape.